# Getting EventArgs when using interaction triggers

Tags: wpf, xaml, mousewheel, interaction, eventtrigger

I'm using this way to catch events from XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
        <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="ChangeValue" TargetObject="{Binding DataContext}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This way works well, I can fire my `ChangeValue` function in my code.
But I would like to know the mouse wheel orientation (up or down) on my `ChangeValue` function.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/)'s [`EventToCommand`](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b922e8ccf674#GalaSoft.MvvmLight%2fGalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET4%29%2fCommand%2fEventToCommandVS10.cs), which also has a `PassEventArgsToCommand` property. Then, instead of a method, define a command that receives the event args as a parameter. Your XAML should look something like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseWheel">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ChangeValueCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So the only way to do that is to use a third library?

Comment: It's the simplest way. You don't have to use the entire MVVM Light library - you can browse its source and only take the `EventToCommand` class.

Comment: Thank you. And with only this class, do you know how to send the event to my data context?

Comment: You should define the `ChangeValueCommand` command in your data context and bind against it like any other binding.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the technique described here:

http://blog.roboblob.com/2010/01/26/binding-ui-events-from-view-to-commands-in-viewmodel-in-silverlight-4/

The blog posting there is very clear and easy to follow, especially if you already have some WPF/Silverlight experience.  I did not run into any problems when I was implementing this version of Event->Command pattern.

This capability is also available, "built in", to frameworks such as MVVMLight.

In essence, you create a Command (ICommand) for each event you want to consume.